# How to Loop thru Listbox and perform repeated task

Tags: excel, vba, loops

My problem is trying to repeat my code for each entry in a listbox on my userform. The code below will do it for one entry, but i need to do it for each item in the list box. My ListBox looks like this.

```
'ListBox
PBB
ABH
GKB
```

This code opens a template workbook and saves it based on the name in the listbox. It then inputs data to the new workbook.
    Option Explicit
    Dim DIV As String
    Dim XL As Excel.Application
    Dim WBK As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ActBook As Workbook
    Dim CurrentFile As Workbook
    Dim NewFileType As String
    Dim NewFile As String
    Dim QTR_NUM As String
    Dim MFG As String
    Dim JOB As String
    Dim visitdate As Variant
    Dim visitdate_text As String
    Dim Quote_Request As Worksheet
    Dim QTR As Workbook
    Dim FORM As Workbook
    Dim DCSProgram As Workbook
    Dim ILast As Long
    Dim j As Integer

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    ' Prevents screen refreshing.

Set DCSProgram = ActiveWorkbook


Set QTR = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Geoffrey\Dropbox\DCS PROGRAM\FILES\1. QUOTES\3. PROGRAM FILES\QTR.xlsx")

ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized


For j = 0 To QTRList.ListCount - 1

MFG = QTRList.List(j)

visitdate = Date
visitdate_text = Format$(visitdate, "mm\-dd\-yyyy")

QTR.SaveAs FileName:="C:\QTR" & "\DCS QTR " _
& " " & MFG & " " & JobName & " " & visitdate_text & " .xlsm", _
FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False, local:=True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set FORM = Workbooks.Open("C:\QTR" & "\DCS QTR " _
& " " & MFG & " " & JobName & " " & visitdate_text & " .xlsm")


With FORM.Sheets(1).Range("H9")
.Value = Date
.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
End With

FORM.Sheets(1).Range("H13").Value = JobName                   'JOB NAME

With DCSProgram.Sheets("MFG_DATA")
    ILast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To ILast
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = MFG Then
            FORM.Sheets(1).Range("B7").Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
            FORM.Sheets(1).Range("B8").Value = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            FORM.Sheets(1).Range("B9").Value = .Cells(i, 4).Value
            FORM.Sheets(1).Range("B12").Value = .Cells(i, 5).Value
            FORM.Sheets(1).Range("B13").Value = .Cells(i, 6).Value
            FORM.Sheets(1).Range("B14").Value = .Cells(i, 7).Value
            FORM.Sheets(1).Range("B15").Value = .Cells(i, 8).Value

   End If: Next: End With
   Next j

   End Sub
```

Im trying to have the above code then repeat for the next item in listbox, ABH and GKB. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. Thanks Again, Geoff

Comment: Your values will always be printed in the range B7:B15. If you don't make this dynamic you will always receive only one line with a result and this will be the last result... and maybe you'll have to change the following MFG = QTRList.List(j) to QTRList.List(j).Value.

Comment: Thanks Kathara, Im doing some research on the dynamic ranges. Im not sure if i want the range B7:B15 to change? This will be the same cells on each sheet. Also i entered the line of code you suggested and it causes an error, error syntax. I'm still a newb so i really appreciate the suggestions. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the listbox items using something like this:

```
For i = 0 To QTRList.ListCount - 1
   MsgBox (QTRList.List(i))
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Xavier, Im still getting the hang of For statements, but this causes an error because im using a For statement already in my code above.

Comment: Maybe the error is because you are using the same variable, if you use one with "i" and another with "j" shouldn't be any error.

Comment: Cool, That worked but not im getting an automation error on my save as line.

Comment: Did you declare/set the variable "Jobname"?